# Enable TLS1.2 in .NET 4.5 applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, tls1.2

Official Microsoft documentation [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) that in order to enable TLS1.2 communication between .NET 4.5 applications the best practice is to target projects to .NET Framemork 4.7. But there are another sources saying that changing  `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />` in Web.config is enough. I'm little bit confused what has to be done to enable TLS1.2 communication (I want to avoid hardcoding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` in code) . Should all packages, libraries be migrated to 4.7 or just this change in web.config is enough?

Comment: If you don't want to go through upgrading the target framework and you want to avoid hard-coding the call to SecurityProtocol you could just add a new config file setting to turn it on or off as needed.